# How can I use leaflet-semicircle with vue2-leaflet in a VueJS project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, vue2leaflet

I use [Vue2Leaflet](https://github.com/vue-leaflet/Vue2Leaflet)
and [Leaflet-semicircle](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet-semicircle). I don't have a problem when using Vue2Leaflet, but I don't know how to use Leaflet-semicircle in my VueJS project.

```
<script>
    import { latLng } from "leaflet";
    import { LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker, LCircleMarker, LPopup, LTooltip } from "vue2-leaflet";
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
    import moment from 'moment';
    import 'leaflet-semicircle';

    export default {
        name: 'Map',
        components: { LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker, LCircleMarker, LPopup, LTooltip, LSemicircle },
        data() {
            return {
            map: null,
            zoom: 12,
            center: latLng(53.88694, 27.554572),
            url: 'http://192.168.1.1/osm-tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            withPopup: latLng(53.88694, 27.524572),
            withTooltip: latLng(53.88694, 27.565572),
            currentZoom: 12,
            currentCenter: latLng(53.88694, 27.554572),
            showParagraph: false,
            mapOptions: {
                zoomSnap: 0.5
            },
            showMap: true
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            this.map = this.$refs.map.mapObject;
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.map = this.$refs.map.mapObject;
            });                  
        },
        updated() {
            L.semiCircle(latLng(53.88694, 27.554572), { // not working
                radius: 5000,
                startAngle: 45,
                stopAngle: 360
            }).addTo(this.map);
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters('targetControl', { events: 'getEvents'}),
        },
        ...
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this problem:

```
import L from "leaflet";
import 'leaflet-semicircle';

latLng changed by L.latLng
```

I just didn't have L function from leaflet

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it's probably not exact answer you need but still.

I see a few options:

1) Check sources https://github.com/vue-leaflet/Vue2Leaflet/blob/master/src/components/LCircle.vue and based on that component create your own (API from  Leaflet-semicircle says that is shouldn't be a headache )

2) Check page https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.com/plugins/ there are a list of plugins. The closest one is probably https://github.com/ais-one/vue2-leaflet-tracksymbol It added another leaflet plugin functionality to vue2leaflet

and by analogy create your own plugin for that

3) the hacky one. You can override the original circle component on leaflet class (I do not recommend to do that, but it's still an option)